# Redirect to home page after submit form vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

i have created login with rest-full api login system with vue 2 laravel 
i want after login it should redirect to another page like / 
i have tried with add then redirect: '/' 
here is my script

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
        loginDetails:{
            email:'',
            password:'',
            remember:true
        },
        errorsEmail: false,
        errorsPassword: false,
        emailError:null,
        passwordError:null
        }
    },
    methods:{
    loginPost(){
        let vm = this;
        axios.post('/login', vm.loginDetails)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errors = error.response
            if(errors.statusText === 'Unprocessable Entity'){
                if(errors.data){
                    if(errors.data.email){
                       vm.errorsEmail = true
                       vm.emailError = _.isArray(errors.data.email) ? errors.data.email[0]: errors.data.email
                    }
                    if(errors.data.password){
                       vm.errorsPassword = true
                       vm.passwordError = _.isArray(errors.data.password) ? errors.data.password[0] : errors.data.password
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
    },
    mounted() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may help

```
 loginPost(){
        axios.post('/login', this.loginDetails)
        .then(function (response) { 
            if(response.status === 200) {
               this.$router.push({ path : '/' });
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Still not Redirecting

Comment: can you provide the controller for the login request

Comment: I haven't change controller its a default Auth system

Comment: laravel login system return a redirect  value so to make this work you have to specify the return value like using `return response()->make(["success" => true])->setStatusCode(200) ;` read more about [Laravel responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses)